# Adding slices to the tips of a phylogeny using ggtree or ape

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtree

I am trying to plot thin slices at the bottom of my phylogeny to visualize the distribution of a particular trait. Similar to this plot:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to do it in either ape or ggtree frameworks.

Here is some code that shows how far I have got:

```
library(ggtree)
library(tidytree)
library(ape)

n = 100
x = rcoal(n)
d = data.frame(label = x$tip.label,
               trait = sample(x = 0:1, size = n, replace = TRUE))
               
## ggtree
x_join = full_join(as_tibble(x), d, by = "label")
tree_df = as.treedata(x_join)

ggtree(tree_df) + 
  geom_tippoint(aes(colour = factor(trait)))


## ape: Only plotting squares 
plot(x)
tiplabels(pch = 15, col = ifelse(d$y == 1, "black", "red"))
```